# Lock and unlock token smart contract

Tags: tokens, ethereum-wallet-dapp, smart-contract-wallets, smart-lock, escrow

What is best way to write a smart-contract that can allow manual locking and unlocking of  token specified by user without requiring transaction fee?
say and escrow lock and unlock of of asset.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly, then it is not absolutely necessary to develop it yourself, you can already use ready-made services like openlock.io